# pop up jquery dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

hey frenz I  have a problem with the jquery-ui dialog box. The problem is that when I close the dialog box and then I click on the link that triggers it, it does not pop-up again unless i refresh the page or save any data in the dialog box.

Code i used is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $("<div></div>")
                    .addClass("dialog")
                    .attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))
                    .appendTo("body")
                    .dialog({
                        close: function () {
                            $(this).remove();
                        },
                        modal: true
                    })
                    .load(this.href);
        });

        $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe replace ```$(this).closest('.dialog')``` with just ```$('.dialog')```. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jud4L/1/

Comment: Your code works - http://jsfiddle.net/cJNfF/ Which jQuery/jQueryUI version do you use?

Comment: Why don't you just create the dialog once and for all with `autoOpen: false` and open/close it ?

Answer (score 0):

1. What [@MattBradley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871132/matt-bradley) said.
2. In this line, `.attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))`, you'r trying to grab the new `<div>`'s `data-dialog-id` attribute an assigning the new `<div>`'s an `id` attribute.  I'm pretty sure you meant to assign the link's `data-dialog-id` attribute to the new `<div>`.
3. `close: function() { $(this).remove(); }` is redundant. Unless you meant "remove the link", not the dialog itself, in which case you would use `link` instead of `this` (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ag6wj/)).
4. *"As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in preference to .live()."*
   Taken from jQuery's [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) documentation.

---

```
$('body').on('click', '.openDialog', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var link = $(this);

    $("<div></div>")
        .addClass("dialog")
        .attr("id", $(link).attr("data-dialog-id"))
        .appendTo("body")
        .dialog({
            modal: true
        })
        .load($(link).attr('href'),  {
            html: "<p>Text echoed back to request</p>"
        });
});

$('body').on("click", '.close', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
});
```

**Demo here:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ag6wj/

Comment: Demo was awesome and i did the same thing in my code but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by injecting another div with an hourglass/spinning-wheel "Please Wait" loading image. (I'm using jquery-1.7.1)

Try replacing this line:

```
$("<div></div>")
```

With this:

```
$("<div><div style='text-align: center'><img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/loading.gif")' alt='Please Wait...' width='100px'/></div></div>")
```

This is my working code (exactly as the original post, except for the one line):

```
// these are for the popup dialogs
// need to use live instead of click because object doesnt exist on ready and will give an objectexpected
$(".openDialog, .editDialog").live("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // this div is duplicate of 'loading' div below
    $("<div><div style='text-align: center'><img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/loading.gif")' alt='Please Wait...' width='100px'/></div></div>")
        .addClass("dialog")
        .attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))
        .appendTo("body")
        .dialog({
            // NOTE: This is where the size of the popup window is set
            width: 800,
            position: 'top',
            title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
            close: function() { $(this).remove(); },
            modal: true
        })
        .load(this.href);
});
```